# How to export mysql table to xml file using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, xml, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a project with laravel 4. I am trying to export MySQL data to XML document. I have managed to save an .xml file however there is no data inside it, or when I add ->get() method to $sales the error pops up.

How could I export selected data from the database to an xml file? I am aiming to create something like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTIfp.png)

```
$sales = Sale::where('Status', '=', 'ON')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc'); //->get() here brings an error.

    try
    {

        $xml = new XMLWriter();

        $xml->openURI('documents/mailouts/example.xml');

        $xml->startDocument('1.0');

        $xml->startElement('sales');

        foreach ($sales as $sale) {


            $xml->startElement('sale');

            $xml->startElement('REF', $sale->SaleID);
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('COUNTY', $sale->county);
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('BOP1', $sale->SaleBop1);
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('OFFICE', $sale->SaleOffice);
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->endElement();
        }

        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->endDocument();

        $xml->flush();

        Session::flash('success', 'success.');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        Session::flash('error','problem');
    }


    return Redirect::route('sendouts.generate');
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve it!.

Instead of starting new elements I have written to an element. My bad for wrong usage.

```
$sales = Sale::where('Status', '=', 'ON')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc'); //->get() here brings an error.

try
{

    $xml = new XMLWriter();

    $xml->openURI('documents/mailouts/example.xml');

    $xml->startDocument('1.0');

    $xml->startElement('sales');

    foreach ($sales as $sale) {


        $xml->startElement('sale');

        $xml->writeElement('REF', $sale->SaleID);
        $xml->writeElement('COUNTY', $sale->county);
        $xml->writeElement('BOP1', $sale->SaleBop1);
        $xml->writeElement('OFFICE', $sale->SaleOffice);


        $xml->endElement();
    }

    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();

    $xml->flush();

    Session::flash('success', 'success.');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    Session::flash('error','problem');
}


return Redirect::route('sendouts.generate');
```

Answer (score 0):

public function xml()

```
{
    $sales = Order::all();//OR $sales = Order::where('xxx')->get();

    try
    {

        $xml = new XMLWriter();

        $xml->openURI('file.xml');

        $xml->startDocument('1.0');
        $xml->startElement('ListOrder');
        $xml->setIndent(4);
        $i=1;
        foreach ($sales as $s){
            $xml->startElement('Order'.$i);
            $xml->writeElement('id', $s->id);
            $xml->writeElement('order_item_id', $s->order_item_id);
            $xml->writeElement('lazada_id', $s->lazada_id);
            $xml->writeElement('seller_sku', $s->seller_sku);
            $xml->writeElement('lazada_sku', $s->lazada_sku);
            $xml->writeElement('updated_at', $s->updated_at);
            $xml->writeElement('order_number', $s->order_number);
            $xml->writeElement('shipping_address3', $s->shipping_address3);
            $xml->writeElement('unit_price', $s->unit_price);
            $xml->writeElement('shipping_fee', $s->shipping_fee);
            $xml->writeElement('item_name', $s->item_name);
            $xml->writeElement('tracking_code', $s->tracking_code);
            $xml->endElement();
            $i++;
    }
        $xml->endElement();


        $xml->endDocument();

        $xml->flush();

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }

}// Trí_Pro
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcKix.png)

Comment: Is this an answer? What is this block of code supposed to be?